# Combining validators in applicative style in Haskell

Tags: haskell, composition, applicative

I have a good grasp on imperative programming, but now I learn myself a Haskell for great good.

I think, I have a good theoretical understanding of Monads, Functors and Applicatives, but I need some practice. And for practice I sometimes bring some bits from my current work tasks.

And I'm stuck a bit with combining stuff in applicative way

## First question

I have two functions for validation:

```
import Prelude hiding (even)

even :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
even x = if rem x 2 == 0 then Just x else Nothing

isSmall :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
isSmall x = if x < 10 then Just x else Nothing
```

Now I want `validate :: Integer -> Maybe Integer` built from `even` and `isSmall`

My best solution is

```
validate a = isSmall a *> even a *> Just a
```

And it's not point free

I can use a monad

```
validate x = do
  even x
  isSmall x
  return x
```

But why use Monad, if (I suppose) all I need is an Applicative? (And it still not point free)

Is it a better (and more buitiful way) to do that?

## Second question

Now I have two validators with different signatures:

```
even = ...

greater :: (Integer, Integer) -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)
-- tuple's second element should be greater than the first
greater (a, b) = if a >= b then Nothing else Just (a, b)
```

I need `validate :: (Integer, Integer) -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)`, which tries `greater` on the input tuple and then `even` on the tuple's second element.

And `validate' :: (Integer, Integer) -> Maybe Integer` with same logic, but returning tuple's second element.

```
validate  (a, b) = greater (a, b) *> even b *> Just (a, b)
validate' (a, b) = greater (a, b) *> even b *> Just  b
```

But I imagine that the input tuple *"flows"* into `greater`, then *"flows"* into some kind of composition of `snd` and `even` and then only single element ends up in the final `Just`.

What would a haskeller do?

Comment: Why do all these return `Just input` on success? Wouldn't a simpler `True` provide the same information?

Comment: It wouldn't be an Applicative then, and I want to learn how to use Applicatives

Comment: Applicative is a bit of an abuse here.  The only "abstraction" you really need here is `Monoid`.  `Applicative` is as useless in this case as `Monad`, heh.  if you're trying to understand Applicatives, looking for contrived use cases where they ad no value is probably not a productive route :)

Comment: This might make more sense if you were trying a transform that might fail, such as String -> Maybe Int.

Comment: It seems like you two very simple functions: `validate k x = k x *> pure x` and `bool2A x = if x then pure () else empty` - then you have simply `validate (bool2A . Prelude.even)` and `validate (bool2A . (<10))` - and it should be obvious hows to compose functions type `a -> Bool` in the way you want (hint: its `liftA2 (&&)` - and `liftA2 (||)` gets the dual of "both conditions hold" which is "either condition holds")  - so your first example is very simply `validate (bool2A . liftA2 (&&) (<10) Prelude.even)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are writing validators of the form `a -> Maybe b` you are more interested in that whole type than in the `Maybe` applicative. The type `a -> Maybe b` are the Kleisli arrows of the `Maybe` monad. You can make some tools to help work with this type.

For the first question you can define

```
(>*>) :: Applicative f => (t -> f a) -> (t -> f b) -> t -> f b
(f >*> g) x = f x *> g x

infixr 3 >*>
```

and write

```
validate = isSmall >*> even
```

Your second examples are

```
validate = even . snd >*> greater
validate' = even . snd >*> fmap snd . greater
```

These check the conditions in a different order. If you care about evaluation order you can define another function `<*<`.

### ReaderT

If you use the type `a -> Maybe b` a lot it might be worth creating a `newtype` for it so that you can add your own instances for what you want it to do. The `newtype` already exists; it's [`ReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT), and its instances already do what you want to do.

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

When you use the type `r -> Maybe a` as a validator to validate and transform a single input `r` it's the same as `ReaderT r Maybe`. The [`Applicative` instance for `ReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.html#line-136) combines two of them together by applying both of their functions to the same input and then combining them together with  `<*>`:

```
instance (Applicative m) => Applicative (ReaderT r m) where
    f <*> v = ReaderT $ \ r -> runReaderT f r <*> runReaderT v r
    ...
```

`ReaderT`'s `<*>` is almost exactly the same as `>*>` from the first section, but it doesn't discard the first result. `ReaderT`'s `*>` is exactly the same as `>*>` from the first section.

In terms of `ReaderT` your examples become

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.ReaderT

checkEven :: ReaderT Integer Maybe Integer
checkEven = ReaderT $ \x -> if rem x 2 == 0 then Just x else Nothing

checkSmall = ReaderT Integer Maybe Integer
checkSmall = ReaderT $ \x -> if x < 10 then Just x else Nothing

validate = checkSmall *> checkEven
```

and

```
checkGreater = ReaderT (Integer, Integer) Maybe (Integer, Integer)
checkGreater = ReaderT $ \(a, b) = if a >= b then Nothing else Just (a, b)

validate = checkGreater <* withReaderT snd checkEven
validate' = snd <$> validate
```

You use one of these `ReaderT` validators on a value `x` by `runReaderT validate x`

Answer (score 5):

You ask why use Monad if all you need is Applicative?  I can ask -- why use Applicative if all you need is Monoid?

All you're doing is essentially trying to take advantage of monoidal behavior/a Monoid, but trying to do it through an Applicative interface.  Kind of like working with `Int`'s through their string representation (implementing `+` for the strings `"1"` and `"12"` and working with strings instead of just `1` and `12` and working with ints)

Note that you can get an `Applicative` instance from any `Monoid` instance, so finding a Monoid that can solve your problem is the same as finding an Applicative that can.

```
even :: Integer -> All
even x = All (rem x 2 == 0)

isSmall :: Integer -> All
isSmall x = All (x < 10)

greater :: (Integer, Integer) -> All
greater (a, b) = All (b > a)
```

To prove that they are the same, we can write conversion functions back and forth:

```
convertToMaybeFunc :: (a -> All) -> (a -> Maybe a)
convertToMaybeFunc f x = guard (getAll (f x)) $> x

-- assuming the resulting Just contains no new information
convertFromMaybeFunc :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> All)
convertFromMaybeFunc f x = maybe (All False) (\_ -> All True) (f x)
```

You could directly write your `validate`:

```
validate :: Int -> All
validate a = isSmall a <> even a
```

But you could also write it in the lifted style you want:

```
validate :: Int -> All
validate = isSmall <> even
```

Want do notation?

```
validate :: Int -> All
validate = execWriter $ do
    tell isSmall
    tell even
    tell (other validator)

validate' :: (Int, Int) -> All
validate' = execWriter $ do
    tell (isSmall . fst)
    tell (isSmall . snd)
    tell greater
```

As you can see, every `Monoid` instance begets an `Applicative`/`Monad` instance (through `Writer` and `tell`), which makes this a bit convenient.  You can think of `Writer`/`tell` here as "lifting" a `Monoid` instance to a free `Applicative`/`Monad` instance.

In the end, you're noticing a design pattern/abstraction that is useful, but it's really the *monoid* that you're noticing.  You're fixated on working on that monoid through an Applicative interface, somehow...but it might be simpler to just work with the monoid directly.

Also,

```
validate :: Int -> All
validate = mconcat
  [ isSmall
  , even
  , other validator
  ]
```

is arguably comparable in clarity to the do notation version w/ Writer :)

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty far-fetched.

Comment: to be fair, the "use a Monoid through Writer/Applicative/Monad" pattern is a pretty common one across the Haskell ecosystem